# Variations in solubility of total dissolved salts in water with temperature

Tags: solubility, water-treatment

I want to know the solubility of "total dissolved salts" or mainly Calcium Chloride and Magnesium Chloride causing hardness of water.

Is this data published anywhere at different temperatures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google is your friend. Using "Calcium chloride solubility", you find plenty of references where this solubility is given at different temperatures. Expressed in grams $\ce{CaCl2}$ in $100$ mL water, it is $59.5$ à $0°$C, $64.7$ at $10°$C, $100$ at $20°$C, $128$ at $30°$C, $137$ at $50°$C, $147$ at $70°$C, and $159$ at $90°$C. Do the same with Magnesium chloride.